# Create a snapshot of hard drive for Synology DiskStation NAS

Tags: backup, nas, synology

I am currently using my DiskStation DS415+ with TimeMachine for OS X. But in addition to this, I would also make a "snapshot" or a "lockdown" if you will, of the file contents on my computer.

What would be the most effective way to do this?

I have almost 1.5 TB of files and manually copying all of the files via Finder would probably not be a reliable way to accomplish the task.

Is there any DiskStation package or other software that can assist me?

Should I create the backup as a "bundled" package or should I opt to copy the files individually? 
Since I already have a bundled backup with TimeMachine, perhaps I should just try to copy over the files individually?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here, and what you're asking is going to get a lot of opinion based answers which doesn't help you or the community. Time Machine, surely, allows you to create a "recovery" set so that you can reinstall OS X and then restore the set bavk so your machine is restored... Much like Windows Backup.

Comment: @BigChris I haven't asked for product recommendations, I have asked for an effective and efficient way to do a file-per-file snapshot of the drive without manually copying it with Finder. Yes, I could possibly make a TimeMachine backup and then prevent it from continuously backing up to it, although that would bundle up my files.

Comment: " Is there any DiskStation package or other software that can assist me?" - clearly a product recommendation request. There are a number of "effective" ways of doing it, of course, if you want a way of not backing up an entire set every time you could look at incremental backup strategies so that only changes to the files are copied to your backup.

Comment: I don't know why you look at a question which is entirely subsidiary to the main question which was "What would be the most effective way to do this?". FYI, the only thing off topic here insofar has been your comments.

Comment: When a question asking "what's the most effective" then you will almost certainly get lots of opinion based answers which, although helpful, doesn't really help because different things work better for different situations and everyone's setups are different. If you want to "snapshot" a disk then you could TimeMachine, you could use `dd`, you could create a RAID1 array and regularly swap/rebuild so you always have a "clone". You see what we mean...

Comment: @BigChris: But 'dd' is a piece of software so suggesting someone use it is off topic! My god people can be pedantic around here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple **utility you already have** on your osx and synology is
**rsync**. It is not a gui and it can't copy your entire machine, but it is
a useful tool for copying lots of files between machines, (or even locally)
and keeping them up to date with minimal network bandwidth.

There are many articles on the web saying how to use it as it is very
popular in the Linux world; here's one for
[osx and synology](https://macsynology.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/rsync-when-time-machine-fails/).

In your case, you might use it just to copy important files from your home
directory to the NAS. They will become files on the NAS you can
browse directly; there is no bundle to unpack.

Interestingly, you can then configure your synology to backup the backup
files to the cloud (google drive etc), and even to encrypt the data on the
way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Norton Ghost is a good recovery management,Disk Cloning, And Back-up tool give it a try or you can look for these other tools too.

https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/faq/352

I personally used Norton Ghost for disk cloning.